# how to read data from kinesis analytics using Lambda function in node js?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I'm trying to read data from kinesis analytics using Lambda function in node JS,
I'm getting data in an encoded format when I'm trying to decode it I'm not getting any output.

```
console.log('Loading function');
const zlib = require('zlib');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    let success = 0;
    let failure = 0;
    const output = event.records.map((record) => {
        // let compressedData = zlib.deflate(record['data'])    
        try {
            // console.log(compressedData.toString('ascii'))
            console.log('saran100000')
            var compressedData = zlib.deflate(record['data'])
            console.log('saran')
            console.log(record.data)
            console.log(compressedData)
            var compAndToString =zlib.deflate(record['data']).toString('utf8')
            console.log('saran1')
            console.log(compAndToString)
            var compAndUncomp = zlib.inflate(zlib.deflate(record['data']))
            console.log('saran2')
            console.log(compAndUncomp)
            var convertBackToString = zlib.inflate(zlib.deflate(record['data'])).toString('utf8')
            console.log('saran3')
            console.log(convertBackToString)   
            success++;
            return {
                recordId: record.recordId,
                // data:result,
                result: 'Ok'
            };
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            failure++;
            return {
                recordId: record.recordId,
                result: 'DeliveryFailed',
            };
        }
    });
    console.log(`Successful delivered records ${success}, Failed delivered records ${failure}.`);
    return { records: output };
};
```

I have also tried the code in the following link
[click here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/preprocessing-data-in-amazon-kinesis-analytics-with-aws-lambda/)